# LinkedIn does not create an Application, but shows "We're getting things cleaned up" message

Tags: linkedin-api

On https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps page there is a "Create Application" button. When all the registration data are filled and the form is submitted, then the site shows "We're getting things cleaned up. We'll be back soon." 
This issue appears on chrome and firefox browsers during all the week.
Could anyone help me to create an application on linkedin?

Minor: i do apologize to ask this, but the only reason i've asked, because  linkedin support team reject to help me with it until i do not ask it on StackOverflow.

Comment: LinkedIn sent you to StackOverflow for technical support?

Comment: it was said smth like that theirs technical team monitors StackOverflow, but the support team can not do anything with the issue. 
more precisely : "I'm unable to troubleshoot any API related issues and the StackOverflow site would be best to be reached by a member of our API team."

Comment: Just want to close the loop here.  LinkedIn help has been instructed to suggest people to consult Stack Overflow for programming/API related support, not general technical support about LinkedIn itself - but that message gets misinterpreted by both sides of the support equation on occasion.

Regarding the issue itself, there's an error related to logo image processing that's been patched and will be deployed very soon.  Ensure you provide an 80x80px JPG or PNG logo in sRGB colour format and you should be able to complete your task without error.

Comment: Thank you very much, @JustinKominar. That's true. My fault was in wrong image file. Now, I've got app keys, and all is fine. Thank you again.

Comment: This is still an issue. LinkedIn has no plan to fix the error message? I was using a icon file and it broke the application.

Comment: This form is very useful demonstration of very bad validation. People spend time filling it in when creating new application, and then snap... all input is lost. I demonstrate it as a bad example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Stack Overflow is not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/19750)

Comment: @JoshLee I have no objections, but there is a question (some guys faced an issue), and there is the answer in comments above. why don't allow some other guys see it in future.